# How do I round a decimal result up in Thymeleaf (same behavior as Math.ceil)?

Tags: thymeleaf, ceil

I am doing table pagination logic for my project using Thymeleaf.

I have two values:

1. int totalRows
2. int rowsPerPage

The operation I want to do is something along the lines of Math.ceil((1.0 + totalRows) / rowsPerPage) to store in a variable that represents the total number of pages necessary.

However, I'm not sure how to do that ceil() operation to convert it from a decimal to an integer.

Comment: can you mark the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working with Spring then you can add a bean that has the method you want Math.ceil. Then call this method in the template. Something like

```
@Component
public class ThymeMath {
    public int ceil(int a, int b) {
        return Math.ceil....
    }
}
```

Then in the template

```
${@thymeMath.ceil(a, b)}
```

That is in the case you really need to do it in Thymeleaf. In the more general case you can calculate the variable in the Java code and add it to the model.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! The bean method didn't occur to me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just call Math.ceil with thymeleaf, use:

```
${T(Math).ceil(yourNumber)}
```

Since Math.ceil returns a double type, you can also encapsulate that in the following expression to remove the trailing ".0" if you wish (the last "1" is the min number of integer digits):

```
${#numbers.formatInteger(T(Math).ceil(yourNumber),1)}
```